# Update specific element in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following structure

```
{
  "_id":"5b609d1a5b4e2c03e512992b", 
  "files_missing":5, 
  "files_rejected":0, 
  "userId":"5afcbbcf26d784ca35fac580", 
  "files":[
           { 
              "status":"sent", 
              "_id":"5b609d1a5b4e2c03e5129930", 
              "fileId":"5afcbad526d784ca35fac576", 
              "urls" [ 
                       { 
                         "_id":"5b60e10114bce7084cebc1da",
                         "file":"/data/5b609d195b4e2c03e512992a.pdf", 
                         "status":"sent"
                       },{ 
                         "_id":"5b60e1ea14bce7084cebc1dd",
                         "file":"/data/5b60e1ea14bce7084cebc1dd.pdf", 
                         "status":"sent"
                       }
                      ]
           }
        ],
  "contactId":"5b609d195b4e2c03e512992a",
  "created_at":"2018-07-31T17:32:10.251Z",
  "updated_at":"2018-07-31T17:32:10.251Z",
  }
```

And I want to update the status inside in one of the elements of urls

I tried:

```
db.collection.update({contactId:"5b609d195b4e2c03e512992a", 
'files.urls._id': "5b60e1ea14bce7084cebc1dd"},{$set: 
{'files.urls.$.status': 'rejected'}})
```

MongoDB version: 3.2.17

Comment: Does files contain only  one element or there may more than one?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet more than one

Comment: Can you update you mongodb version?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet maybe, is arrayFilters the only option?

Comment: Yes  no other option here